# SpringBoot with embedded Jetty does not unpack the war file

Tags: java, spring-boot, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am deploying a war with embedded jetty using SpringBoot. I start it using java -jar .war. The web app run fine, but the war file is not unpacked to any directory. I have tried setting -Djava.io.tmpdir, and even tried customizing JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory and setting the tempDir after extracting the WebAppContext out of the Server. My customizer runs and correctly sets the tempDir, but the war is not unpacked at all.
What do I have to do make it unpack the war file ?

Comment: Have you checked the permission of the war file ? war file might have root permission and you might running tomcat with custom user.

Comment: Why does it need to unpack ?

Comment: Read the title of the users' post?

Comment: Have you Iset <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set> in your configuration?

Comment: Also can you share start up logs

Comment: Yes, extractWAR is set to true

Comment: I need to unpack because I want to enable quick UI development by letting the developers modify the .html, .jsp etc.

Comment: @KartikMehta that's not how extractWAR works (hint: it's a temp directory behavior), if the timestamp is different it will unpack/extract that resource again.

Comment: It is not extracting/unpacking the war at all in the first place, let alone re-extracting it. Everything is being read by a JarResource from the war file itself